# Properly Defining DAG Schedule Interval

Tags: cron, airflow

Problem: We're having difficulties having a DAG fire off given a defined interval. It's also preventing manual DAG executions as well. We've added `catchup=False` as well to the DAG definition.

Context: We're planning to have a DAG execute on a 4HR interval from M-F. We've defined this behavior using the following CRON expression:

```
0 0 0/4 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

We're unsure at this time whether the interval has been defined properly or if there are extra parameters we're ignoring.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for is [`0 0/4 * * 1-5`](https://crontab.guru/#0_0/4_*_*_1-5) which will run on 4th hour from 0 through 23 on every day-of-week from Monday through Friday.

Your DAG object can be:

```
from airflow import DAG

with DAG(
    dag_id="my_dag",
    start_date=datetime(2022, 2, 22),
    catchup=False,
    schedule_interval="0 0/4 * * 1-5",
) as dag:
    # add your operators here
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. Thank you!